# Django: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: django

Hola amigos estoy practicando con django, cuando le doy `python manage.py runserver` me dice lo siguiente :

> File "C:\proyectodjango\tiendaOnline\tiendaOnline\urls.py", line 18, in 
>       from tiendaOnline.gestionPedidos import  views
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tiendaOnline.gestionPedidos'

[image: captura urls.py]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Hola jose lo hice pero volvi a corrrer el runserver y nada.alguna otra sugerencia?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, considera compartir tu código en formato de texto, y añadiste el módulo a tus settings.py?

Comment: Parece que tendras que agregar 'gestionPedidos' a tu lista de INSTALLED_APPS en tiendaOnline.settings.py

Answer (score 1):

Debido a que me ocurrió el mismo error y he encontrado solución, comparto aquí:

Mi **settings.py** contenía lo siguiente:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'Aplicaciones.Gestion',
]
```

Mientras que mi apps.py era tal que:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class GestionConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'Gestion'
```

El error al migrar era el siguiente: **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Gestion'**

Por lo que tuve que **corregir el archivo apps.py** con:

```
class GestionConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'Aplicaciones.Gestion'
```

Por tanto, es necesario asegurarse de tal detalle.